# How can I TryParse userinput?

Tags: c++-cli

this is my problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define newline '\n'
using namespace std;
using namespace System;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
bool isNumber;
String^ age;
Int32 result;
cout
    << "Please enter your age:"
    << newline;
cin >> age;
isNumber = Int32::TryParse(age, result);
return 0;
}
```

I cant use cin with a String^ and I can't use string to tryparse

Comment: You're mixing Apples with Tomatoes. If you target .NET (then C++/CLI) then don't use `cin`/`cout` but `Console::ReadLine()` and `Console::WriteLine()`. If you compile in C++ (then unmanaged) don't use `String^` and `Int32::TryParse` because they're .NET stuff. Parsing in C++ is done with `std::stoi`. A side note: `TryParse` won't return parsed value but a boolean to indicate if value has been parsed successfully. Another note: you have `endl`, you don't need a constant for new line.

Comment: Well then decide what you want to use: C++/CLI or C++. They're **pretty different** (not only because of library).